# Would this circuit work on AMS1117?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

Just a quick question. is this a correct circuit? would it drive 500mA device? given using AMS1117 as the regulator? Do we need to add heatsink? any alternative to step down the 12V to 3.3V without using heatsink?

[image]

Comment: What will be the voltage drop across R1 when the regulator is delivering 500 mA?

Comment: Wanna use a battery source for 12V so 12V to 5V I guess.

Comment: Remember that the full output current must pass through R1. (Hint: voltage dividers make very poor power sources)

Comment: No this will **NOT** work 1) the resistive divider R1, R2 will only output 5 V when **no current flows**. At 800 mA load you will get a couple of millivolt. Using a voltage divider here is **silly** it will not work. Only use a resistor voltage divider if you need a few mA or less. 2) An AMS1117 is not suitable to dissipate 5V - 3.3V = 1.7 V; 1.7 V * 0.8A = 1.36 W even on a heatink the size of a house it will **overheat**. Instead of all this, use an **LM2596** based **switched regulator** module. Find these on eBay for less than $2. These do not need a heatsink.

Comment: The reason I used voltage divider was I want to lower the amount of Voltage drop that AMS has to endure, lowering its heat dissipation to be able to use it without a heatsink. I am not an electronic engineer, so just asking.

Comment: The only way to avoid a heatsink is a **switched** regulator, you could use a series (power) resistor but that will also get HOT.

Comment: Here's what you need: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-LM2596-power-Supply-Buck-Converter-step-down-module-GM-/262136732989  Connect input to 12 V, adjust screw on blue pot to output = 3.3 V: done!

Comment: The proper way to reduce the power dissipated by the regulator is with a small resistance *in series* with the regulator input, but in this situation it will still have the regulator dissipate too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not correct.

First: imagine you connect only 2,8k from 12V to GND. I = U / R = 12V / 2800 Ohm = 0,00428 A = 4mA. No current higher than that will ever be sourced from 12V.

You can connect the 1117 directly to 12V. It will disspate (12V-3,3V)*0,8A Watts. 6,96W will make it run hot.

You could add a power resistor in front of the regulator (from 12V to regulator input). If you wanted for example to drop 12V to 5V first (drop of 7V) and then regulate. The resistor value would be R = U / I = 7V / 0,8A = 8,75 Ohms. At 0,8A that resistor would dissipate P = I^2 * R = 5,6 W. You should pick a power resistor with higher power rating than that.

In the end you have to dissipate those ~7 watts somewhere (either in the regulator or power resistor) unless you use a switching regulator.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't work even with zero load, let alone with 800mA

The regulator needs 5mA typical (11mA maximum) Iq.

The regulator drops out at 1.1V typical (1.3V maximum),  a bit less at lower currents.

So if the regulator drops at 1.1V we need 4.4V in. There is 5mA going into the regulator with no load and 2.2mA going into R2 for a total of 7.2mA plus the load current.

That means we need an input voltage of 7.2mA * 2.8K + 4.4V or about 24V for it to fire up even with no load at all. I guess the good news is that you won't need a heat sink, but it won't work at all.

---

Use a switching supply chip or module such as the ubiquitous fake LM2596 modules from China.

Otherwise you will need a large heat sink or a fan in order to dissipate 0.8A * (12-3.3) = 7W. You could drop some of that with a resistor in series with the input but it will still get hot and require a heatsink.